# Python open doesn't create a file per the docs

Tags: python

I find it hard to believe that python still has a problem creating files in 2020...So, I'm assuming it's windows or me...

Here is the code with output.

I have tried modes w, w+, wt with the error message below. The whole point of using w, w+, wt is that the file is created if it doesn't exist

I have changed to using Path.touch, and then using a, a+ modes which just gives and error **enter**

```
import sys
print("Python version:")
print (sys.version)

import platform
print("Platform: {} - {} - {}".format(platform.system(), platform.release(), platform.version()))

from pathlib import Path
output = 'hello world!'
save_dir = Path.cwd().joinpath("./sw_out")
if(save_dir.exists() == False):
    save_dir.mkdir()
    print("dir exists now: {}".format(save_dir.exists()))

debug_file = save_dir.joinpath("my_debug.txt")
#debug_file.touch(exist_ok=True)
print(str(debug_file))
with(open(debug_file), 'w+') as f:
    f.write(output)
f.close()
```

```
Python version:
3.7.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Dec 26 2019, 23:30:11) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Platform: Windows - 10 - 10.0.17763
dir exists now: True
C:\users\me\project\sw_out\my_debug.txt

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-447d2a994262> in <module>
     16 #debug_file.touch(exist_ok=True)
     17 print(str(debug_file))
---> 18 with(open(str(debug_file)), 'w+') as f:
     19     f.write(output)
     20 f.close()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\users\\me\\project\\sw_out\\my_debug.txt'
```

Comment: Unrelated: Don't call `f.close()` that's done automatically by `with`.

Comment: ok, but it crashes during the open call

Comment: I know, that's why I said my comment is unrelated to the problem.

Comment: You are getting a `FileNotFoundError` which means that file or path doesn't exist on your machine. Double check your filepaths. I'd also suggest checking out the syntax for [Path.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.open). It looks like you're mixing the two conventions

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong.

Change this:

```
with(open(debug_file), 'w+') as f:
```

to:

```
with(open(debug_file, 'w+')) as f:
```

Which is the same as:

```
with open(debug_file, 'w+') as f:
```

Comment: There's also no need for the parentheses around the call to `open()`, that may be what confused him.

Answer (score 0):

Simple change should get this working:

```
with open(debug_file, 'w+') as f:
    f.write(output)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
#debug_file.touch(exist_ok=True)
print(str(debug_file))
with open(debug_file, 'w+') as f:
    f.write(output)
f.close()
```

This worked for me.